# Changing tag [stackoverflow-for-teams] to [stack-overflow-for-teams] etc?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) page in the Help Center says under **How to format tags**:

> - Replace spaces with hyphens (-) to combine multiple words into a single word

The [name of SO is Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/201833/215590) (not StackOverflow) so can the[stackoverflow-for-teams](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-for-teams) tag be merged/renamed to become [stack-overflow-for-teams](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-for-teams)?

In fact, as commented by @Catija there are a number of similar tags starting with "stackoverflow" in their name here that could be similarly improved:

[image]

Also, those with "stackexchange" in their name could do with similar improving:

[image]

Comment: For reference, the MSO tag is `[stackoverflow-for-teams]` so right now they're at least... matching... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368339/can-we-fix-synonymize-the-tags-on-mso-that-refer-to-stackoverflow-instead-of Also, as with that request, there are about a dozen tags here on MSE that fail to have a dash in them ... so right now it's consistent with all of the tags here. That's not saying I disagree... only that if they change this one, they should change them all.

Comment: @Catija I'm hoping fixing one will trigger the fixer to fix them all.

Comment: Considering the answer you already have... you might be better served making the question about all of them.

Comment: Also "stackexchange". :)

Comment: The [stackexchange.com] is correct since the domain name is http://stackexchange.com and not http://stack-exchange.com. But I agree that the other tags should be renamed.

Answer (score 1):

That tag isn't supposed to exist here; in fact its tag wiki says not to use it here.

The only two questions using it currently are a recently-filed bug report (very new) and a question that has been migrated to Meta Stack Overflow.

It might be better to blacklist the tag here, with a prompt to ask the question on Meta Stack Overflow.